# Bash Get all files containing file extension, recursively

Tags: bash

Using Bash how would I get all file names (not paths) of files containing ".cpp", given a root folder to recursively-check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `find`:

```
find /root/folder/to/check -name '*.cpp' -printf "%P\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Just one thing, I made a mistake. I actually need the relative path, offset from ''/root/folder/to/check". So if the next folder was a, then the results would show a/filename.cpp instead of /root/folder/to/check/a/filename.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You can use for that purpose `-printf` option of `find` command with the following parameter:

`%f     File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).`

so the full command may look like this:

```
find / -type f -name "*.cpp" -printf "%f\n"
```